# primefaces fileupload not showing up

Tags: jsf, primefaces

on my web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

on my xhtml

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">  

    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{testController.handleFileUpload}"  
                  mode="advanced"   
                  update="messages"  
                  sizeLimit="100000"   
                  allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"/>  

    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>  

</h:form>
```

already imported the commons-fileupload, and commons-io libraries.

using JSF 2.0 and Primefaces 3.5

my problem is, the upload layout in not displaying, theres no buttons for choose,upload nor cancel.

code reference is here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/single.xhtml

Comment: Have you set the *enctype* of your form to `multipart/form-data` as shown in your reference? Also there are some reports about the importance of the order you include the servlet definition inside your *web.xml* (should go after the facelet-Servlet). Cheers!

Comment: yes, sorry forgot to add the form tag. (updated the question) hmm i quite confuse what you meant on the order of the web.xml

Comment: The order you include additional servlets/filters in your `web.xml` **may be** important. At first there should be the *FacesServlet* and **after** this servlet definition you should insert the PF fileupload filter. But nevertheless its unlikely the reason your component gets rendered. Cheers!

Comment: oh i see, yea i added the primefaces filter after the faces servlet definition, still not working tho :(

Comment: but if i use mode="simple" , browse appears but i need the "advance mode"

Comment: AFAIK is the advanced-mode is reliable on JavaScript. Could you please check for any script-/ad-blocking plugins in your browser. Your code is working fine for me though. Cheers

Comment: Make sure of some things before say that is not displaying: test the code in more than 1 browser (i.e. IEx and Chrome), make a pretty basic sample (like the PrimeFaces Single FileUpload example). With these, you'll be able to isolate the problem and find the real culprit of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the rest of your page has problems.

Do you have *h:head* instead of *head* and *h:body* instead of *body*? If you don't that could cause your components not to render properly.

I would leave this as a comment, but I don't have enough points yet

Comment: i also tried removing other stuff in the page and leave a simple h:head, h:body and the form. still wont render the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MyFaces or Mojarra? The Primefaces Team develop thinking only to work on Mojarra, their Ajax implementation for example didn't work with composite:clientbehavior.

Try with Mojarra.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I spent a few days on this and finnaly I realize that I had in my lib RICHFACES and PRIMEFACES so I decided to delete RICHFACES and the component started to render right! Take a look at this...